# NSOperation finishes in the background, attempts to notify main thread, view no longer exists. Crash

Tags: iphone, multithreading, ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have an NSOperation running not in the main thread. It is spawned from a UITableViewController. When the operation is complete, I'd like to reload the tableview since some data has changed. I've set a delegate for the background to notify on completion. When done, I call a wrapper around reloadData specifically on the main thread using performSelectorOnMainThread.

For the most part, this works well, however, there is a non-0 chance that the original (edit)tableViewController (/edit) gets released and I get zombie calls.

So the question is in 2 parts:

1. Is it possible to have a delegate from the background thread without retaining the object?
2. Is this just a bad design? Should I be using NSNotifications instead? Would that be the preferred method of notifying in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The real question is: why is your table view being released? I have a feeling that the table view is not properly retained, and that is your root problem.

Comment: John is right, you should not release the tableView if you need to reload it again. The reloadData method will reset the tableView and that is what you want. If you are looking to hide it or something, just use tableView.hidden property.

Comment: Correction, the tableViewController could be released if it is popped off the navigation controller stack. The data could still be relevant though so I'd want the thread to finish (and save the data it's processing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A delegate should be retained if there is a possibility that it might be released before any operation on the delegate is invoked. You can set up a state in tableViewController to handle the case when the delegate callback is invoked and the tableViewController is not to be used (Basically make the callbacks act as no-op). Once your operation is done, just release the delegate object.

It is not a bad design but you just need to handle these conditions.

Comment: Interesting. Well, since generally the only thing that happens after the response returns is that the tableview reloads, I could just let the tableview reload, even if it's not showing, since the delegate retains it, it won't go away, and it won't crash. I just implemented that (by changing assign to retain and releasing when necessary) and I'm testing as we speak.